# What's the problem with my Tab Layout Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-viewpager

today I wanted to code tab layout.But I faced one problem,help me out please.Thank you in advance!I really appreciate it!
Over here my pager adapter class code

```
class MyPagerAdapter(fm: FragmentManager) : FragmentPagerAdapter(fm) {
override fun getCount(): Int {
    return 2
}

override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment {
    when (position) {
        0 -> {
           return FirstFragment()
        }
        1 -> {
           return SecondFragment()
        }
        else -> {
            return FirstFragment()
        }
    }
}

override fun getPageTitle(position: Int): CharSequence? {
    when (position) {
        0 -> {return "History"}
        1 -> {return "Gallery"}
    }
    return super.getPageTitle(position)
}
}
```

Over here my **MainActivity** code:

```
viewPager.adapter = MyPagerAdapter(supportFragmentManager)
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager)
```

The error is "viewPager must not be null"
And it points me to `viewPager.adapter = MyPagerAdapter(supportFragmentManager)` line

Comment: where did you declare your `viewPager`?

Comment: I'm sorry I forgot to add it up :)
That's it
    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="1dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="1dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tabLayout"/>